# Header file not found error while building Code Composer Studio embedded project (with link to an external project) in Ubuntu

Tags: compiler-errors, ide, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I have an embedded project using a TI cross-compiler which is linked to an external project (read, custom-built library). I use Code Composer Studio (CCS) v9 to build the project in Windows. All include dependencies have been added.

I am able to compile and generate the output flash file successfully.

The project is available internally in the GitLab server.

I am now trying to compile the same project in Ubuntu 16.04 using Code Composer Studio v10.

1. I pull the project along with the external dependent-library from GitLab.
2. I imported the CCS project in CCS.
3. All include options have been adapted (including environmental variables, compiler paths etc).

When I try to compile the project, I am getting the following error:

```
#1965 cannot open source file "xyz.h"
```

The source file path is ExternalLibraryFolder/ABC/include/xyz.h

The ExternalLibraryFolder is placed parallel to the actual project folder in both, the Ubuntu and Windows file system.

Steps I tried:

1. Cross-checked all the include options in Linker setting with Windows project.
2. Tried to replicate the same project folder and hierarchy and workspace structure as in Windows system (I know, it's not required).
3. Tried to copy the error-prone .h file in the main project.
4. Checked the cross-compiler version in both the operating systems.
5. Added reference to the external project will imported the main CCS project in CCS.
6. Hard-copied the files in the main project.

All the above steps did not work.

Can anyone please guide me what else can I try to resolve this error ?  Maybe I am missing something ?

Note: I need this because I am trying to implement CI using Jenkins (installed in Ubuntu as bare-metal, no docker etc.).

Comment: Pls edit your question to add the full path to the header file. Compiler issues often occur due to differences between the way Linux and Windows handle file and folder (directory) names.

Comment: Edited the question to include the full path to the header file.